# Multilingual alert messages in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multilingual

I have a php Web Application Multilingual, 
I have a php variable which can tell the current language of the Web Application,

I need to validate user inputs in client side, and error messages are shown with JavaScript alerts

for example if the php language variable is "french", I need the alert as "bonjour"
            if the php language variable is "english", I need the alert as "hello"

any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some sort of dictionary/array for each language you support and depending on which one, include the relevant file or spit out the relevant part in the dictionary.

```
<?php $lang = 'fr'; ?>
<script>
messagesDictionary = {
    en: {
    message:'Hi'
    },

    fr: {
    message:'Bonjour'
    }

}

alert( messagesDictionary['<?php echo $lang;?>']['message'] );
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the dictionary server-side so that the client doesn't have to download a whole dictionary including messages that he will never see?

Answer (score 10):

Use your own namespace

en.js

```
MyApp.lang = {
    greeting: "Hello",
    warning: "Attention"
};
```

de.js

```
MyApp.lang = {
    greeting: "Hallo",
    warning: "Achtung"
};
```

Use it like `alert(MyApp.lang.greeting)` then depending on your php variable include the right .js file in the header

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this functionality is given as

```
var userLang = "<?php echo 'en-Us'; ?>"; 
var Langauges={

"en-US":{
"HelloWorld":'Hi this is Us English'
},
"en-EG":{
"HelloWorld":'Hi this is en English'
},
"en-AU":{

"HelloWorld":'Hi this is Au English'
}
}

alert(Langauges[userLang]["HelloWorld"] )
```