# How to better structure multilingual Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, organization

We are rewriting the jQuery code of our web service and we are thinking on a better way to organize it. We've been reading several SO questions, articles, etc; and this is a first approach, but we would love to receive feedback.

We are going to have a Class for each object of the page (Place, User, etc). We are planning to use [Low Pro](https://github.com/danwrong/low-pro-for-jquery/) ([Article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/05/using-low-pro-for-jquery)) so we have all the code in one place.

However there are some variables that we need to pass from PHP (user.id, user.name, etc). We have thought the best way is to print a json and pass it to a general class.

```
var array = {
  'key1' => 'value',
  'key2' => 'value',
  'key3' => 'value',
};
var te = new TE(array);
```

TE.js will assign variables there so the other classes can use them. As we have a multilingual web, we need to have the messages in several languages. We will do something similar to the answers of [Multilingual alert messages in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657220/multilingual-alert-messages-in-javascript)

What do you think? Is there a better way to load the initial array? Any other suggestion or article?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are finally using [Classy.js](http://classy.pocoo.org/) for having Classes. We have built our own main Class that loads the params we print as a json on the `data-params` attribute of the `body` tag.

We have the translation string for the js classes on two different fields as Tom and Shan suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would store all the translated words in separate JS so that they can be cached by the client, and you wont suffer repeated data (IE, multiple JQuery classes can reference the same index for the same word).

Comment: we want to have a unique JS script that can be cached by the client. Is it crazy to have two versions of the full script, one for English people and other for Spanish people? This full script will include all the jquery plugins, our own classes and the translated words.

Comment: I'd be more worried about design than bandwidth.  Having to maintain the Spanish script and the English script separately can easily cause problems in the future.  I would normalise the data, so to speak, and keep the language in the other file.

Comment: I saw you mentioned there are 300 values.  Even if you have 2000 words that are 30 characters long on average, this is less than 60kb of data.  Yours should be a lot smaller.

Comment: And about the use of Low Pro for classes, and the way to pass general PHP variables, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you linked to will incur a larger bandwidth footprint for clients. If you intend to have thousands of key value pairs, and many different languages, consider having only English key/value pairs streamed to clients, or French key/value pairs streamed to clients.

Comment: exactly, only one language goes to the client (we may have around 300 key/value for JS)

Comment: And it's not significantly greater effort to use this approach.